# What are the root causes for failure of ConfigInstall action?

Tags: windows-installer, registry, installshield, windows-server-2003

I have created one MSI installer in InstallShield. When I'm trying to install this installer on Windows 2003 Server I'm getting following error:

> Action start 5:04:40: ConfigInstall.
>   MSI (c) (F0:6C) [05:04:40:579]:
>   Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\DOCUME~1\AD2738~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\MSI3.tmp,
>   Entrypoint: _ConfigInstall@4
>   MSI (c) (F0:F8) [05:04:40:595]: Cloaking enabled.
>   MSI (c) (F0:F8) [05:04:40:595]: Attempting to enable all disabled
>   privileges before calling Install on Server
>   MSI (c) (F0:F8)
>   [05:04:40:595]: Connected to service for CA interface.
>   Action ended  5:04:40: **ConfigInstall. Return value 3**.

So when I searched for this **return code 3**, I got to know that its a failure of Action. But I didn't get the reason for failure of `ConfigInstall`. I searched a lot for causes of failure of `ConfigInstall`. But I didn't find anything.

So can anyone please tell me what are the main reasons of failure of this action `ConfigInstall`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not finding anything in some quick searches, and these lines indicate this is a custom action, provided by you (or your team) or a third party:

> MSI (c) (F0:6C) [05:04:40:579]:
>   Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
>   C:\DOCUME~1\AD2738~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\MSI3.tmp,
>   Entrypoint: _ConfigInstall@4

If you have the source code, you could consider adding logging or even debugging. If not, you could still try using tools such as Dependency Walker to verify that the DLL's dependencies are available on Windows 2003 Server. (If they don't, you'll have to figure out a means to get them there, possibly by linking them statically, possibly by installing them and executing the CA late enough that they're present.)

Note that 2003 is no longer supported by Microsoft, so this may be a good time to drop support for it yourself.

Comment: Yes Michael. You were right. This customAction was written by previous teammate. But this CustomAction is failing and this is the first CA in the sequence with condition of "1" i.e always execute. So is there any way to skip this CA without making new installer ? either by some command or any other way ?

Comment: Since the action isn't conditioned against something you can override on the command line, you'll have to create a transform or build a new package.